# Switching appsettings.json according to subdomain

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I switch "appsettings.json" file when current subdomain change?

I want to implement multi-tenancy with separate databases.

for example:

When the URL is {x.site.com}, then I connect to database x.

When the URL is {y.site.com}, then I connect to database y.

Answer (score 0):

`appsettings.json` is just a JSON file, not a special file like `app.config` or `web.config` used to be. The configuration system loads settings from *any* configured source (json files, databases, command line, environment variables), with newer settings overriding older ones. This is described in [ASP.NET Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Despite the name, configuration works the same way for all .NET Core applications *and* .NET Old applications using the `Microsoft.Extension.Configuration` NuGet package.

`appsettings.json` is just the default file added by the host builder. The host builder also loads an environment-based file after that by checking an environment variable, eg `appsettings.Production.json` or `appsettings.Staging.json`. Nothing prevents you from loading *another* file called eg `MyFavoriteSettings.json` or, if you like `ini` files, `MySettings.ini` to override the settings loaded by previous files.

To override a connection string defined in `app settings.json`, eg :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

All you have to do is load a setting with the same name (`ConnectionStrings:BloggingDatabase`) as the setting you want to override. For example, in `appsettings.Production.json` you could enter :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=localhost;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

and then, add another settings file, eg `MyCustomerA.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=localhost;Database=CustomerA;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

and register it

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("CustomerA.json", 
                    optional: true, 
                    reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

The [JSON Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider) section has examples that show how to register multiple files.

You could also pass the connection string through an environment variable or command-line parameter. The [default host builder configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration) load environment variables after the `json` files and command line parameters last of all, overriding all previous settings.

In a multi-tenant environment using containers, environment variables would be an excellent way to override connection strings from the outside, without modifying the container itself. The [connection string prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#connection-string-prefixes) section explains how to name connection string environment variables for different database providers,